# assertion of date time issue

Tags: python, pytest, assertion

I'm doing an pytest on this and I see there is T in the middle which is causing me problem it is the type issue where I have changed it to datetime as its type still having this issue.

```
assert model_setup.start_model_duration == start_model_duration
E       AssertionError: assert datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 2, 15, 4, 5) == '2019-06-02T15:04:05'
E         +datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 2, 15, 4, 5)
E         -'2019-06-02T15:04:05'
```

So later I made these two as strings and still that T in the middle is causing an issue

```
assert str(model_setup.start_model_duration) == str(start_model_duration)
E       AssertionError: assert '2019-06-02 15:04:05' == '2019-06-02T15:04:05'
E         - 2019-06-02T15:04:05
E         ?           ^
E         + 2019-06-02 15:04:05
E         ?           ^
```

Comment: try to format this '2019-06-02T15:04:05' using strptime.

Comment: to learn more on formatting string to date you can use this https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing isoformat:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 2, 15, 4, 5)
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2019-06-02T15:04:05'
```

So you can use either of these:

```
# convert the datetime to a string
assert model_setup.start_model_duration.isoformat() == start_model_duration

# convert the string to a datetime
assert model_setup.start_model_duration == datetime.fromisoformat(start_model_duration)
```